# Highlight a Table Row as per the time of the Day in between interval of 45 minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Here is the table I have. I would like to highlight the row of table one after another at interval of 45 minutes depending on which time it is now and should dynamically update while user is on the page.

I have no any idea as I'm not familiar with jquery or javascript. Any help would be much much appreciated.

```
<div class="table">
     <table>

 <tr>  <td id="r1">1</td><td>10:15 - 11:00</td> </tr>

 <tr>  <td id="r3">2</td><td>11:00 - 11:45</td> </tr>

 <tr>  <td id="r5">3</td><td>11:45 - 12:30</td> </tr>

 <tr>  <td id="r7">4</td><td>12:30 - 1:15</td> </tr>

 <tr>  <td id="r9">5</td><td>1:15 - 2:00</td> </tr>

 <tr>  <td id="r11">6</td><td>2:00 - 2:45</td> </tr>

 <tr>  <td id="r13">7</td><td>2:45 - 3:30</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The logic is pretty simple: store time intervals that correspond to the table rows in an array and add a CSS class to one row based on time of day, but you have to give us the code you are working with so far.

Comment: Are you opposed to using additional libraries such as moment.js ? Does it need to highlight just on page load or dynamically update while the user is on the page?

Comment: yes Travis, it must dynamically update while user is on the page. I googled the whole forums and topics but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: Start by learning javascript and jquery... look into setinterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do it with one array of objects, but I'm lazy, so I made one array of times and one of class names. Or, make the ids something based on the time that gets returned (like 'id_1100'). I just made it work with the given example.

Could also get rid of the `now` variable since it's only used once but that would make it even more unreadable.

Oh, this demo won't work if you are viewing it before 10:15 am or after 3:30 pm and I don't update dynamically while the user is on the page, but you can set your own timer and clear/set the background of the correct row.

Edit: might work in Opera Mini

```js
var now = new Date().getHours() * 100 + new Date().getMinutes();
var times = [1015, 1100, 1145, 1230, 1315, 1400, 1445, 1530];
var ids = ['r1', 'r3', 'r5', 'r7', 'r9', 'r11', 'r13'];
var selected = '';
for (var ix = 0; ix < times.length; ix++) {
  if (now >= times[ix]) {
    selected = ids[ix];
  }
}
if (selected) document.getElementById(selected).parentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <td id="r1">1</td>
    <td>10:15 - 11:00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="r3">2</td>
    <td>11:00 - 11:45</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="r5">3</td>
    <td>11:45 - 12:30</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="r7">4</td>
    <td>12:30 - 1:15</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="r9">5</td>
    <td>1:15 - 2:00</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="r11">6</td>
    <td>2:00 - 2:45</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="r13">7</td>
    <td>2:45 - 3:30</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The code is not working, as you had provided. I've also tried running in code snipped but no luck.

Comment: Huh...What browser are you using?

Comment: opera mini..Here is the screenshot of it. As you can see my pc has current time of 2:40, so it supposed to highlight r11 but nope it is just white. http://imgur.com/a/RKpnW I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Aside from using Opera Mini, you aren't doing anything wrong. :D

Comment: yes it is 3:10 here in my country  and still I did tried with google chrome and firefox and internet browser but no any highlights. Only outputs table with white background in all rows and columns.

Comment: Open the developer tools and look for errors in the console. I took a quick look on https://caniuse.com/ to remove things that don't work on Opera Mini but I must have missed something. https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program/

Comment: I didn't notice that one before but suddenly notice that it is working now but now i"m stuck in new problem, I have two tables with two tabs of each of then..like sun and mon. I have given same id to both of them, but it is strange  it only works to first one not the below one. If sun table is above then mon , it works for sun and if it is mon then instead it works for mon. what is the problem and what possible solutions can I have??